# Listening for submit of form NOT working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to disable some buttons on submit of form but I can't seem to get the function to work with my setup. Here is my Javascript:

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form.upload-data-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
  });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<%= form_for @changeset, upload_path(@conn, :create), [class: "upload-data-form", multipart: true], fn f -> %>
```

That ends up having this class `.upload-data-form` When I submit the form the debugger in my Javascript is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `the debugger in my Javascript is not working` - which browser?

Comment: Chrome version 59

Comment: Although above code seems valid, try using `on` method:
```$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});```

Comment: @Rikin That doesn't seem to be working either

Comment: @Bitwise can you see if this outputs anything? `alert( "You are running jQuery version: " + $.fn.jquery );` Chances are your $ sign is not assigned to jQuery.

Comment: when you say "not working" - what happens? if you console.log within the submit handler, does that get output?

Comment: No output if I console.log

Comment: It's just not hitting the function of `on("submit")`

Comment: Ensure `submit` event is triggering. Put this submit button `<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />` within `form` tag and click on it, you should see *debugger*.

Comment: Change that code to ```jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});``` and see if that helps

Comment: So is the form dynamically loaded? Is it found when you bind the submit? `console.log($("form.upload-data-form").length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to event handlers. try delegating events on children of the document object

```
$(document).on("submit","form.upload-data-form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
  });
```

Comment: Code is wrapped inside `.ready` which should suffice that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  $("form.upload-data-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
  });
});
```